# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'i' of non-nullable

Tags: model-view-controller

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'i' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'MvcDemo.Controllers.EmployeeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

This is my controller :

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Employee/

    public ActionResult Details(int i)
    {
        EmployeeContext ec = new EmployeeContext();
        Employee employee = ec.emp.Single(ep => ep.empid == i);
        return View(employee);
    }

}
```

This is my model class :

```
[Table("employee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int empid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string add { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
```

This is DbContext class :

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> emp { get; set; }
}
```

Please tell me what is above error and why it is coming?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: The first most ............error coming in the web browser.